# How assign each folder's label for all image files in it and then give it to model in Python

Tags: python, windows, image-processing, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

There are many folders (each for a patient), and each folder has many image files. There is a CSV file that contains folder names and their corresponding labels.

I want Python to consider every folder’s labels for all files in them and load them (filenames are the same as the parent folder, but the difference is within the [ ] mark). But I don’t know how to assign folder labels for all files in it as machine input.

I'm using this code but the [ */ *] seems to be not correct.

```
data = pd.read_csv("COAD_CMS_label.csv")
training_data, testing_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.25, random_state=25)
y = data['CMS_Subtype']

#add all the training images, store them in a list, and finally convert that list into a numpy array
train_image = []
for i in tqdm(range(data.shape[0])):
    img = image.load_img('tiles/'+training_data['folder_name'][i]+ [*/*] +'.jpg', target_size=(256,256,3), 
                         grayscale=False)
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    train_image.append(img)
X = np.array(train_image)
```

CSV File head:

folder_name,CMS_Subtype

TCGA-A6-2683-01Z-00-DX1.0dfc5d0a-68f4-45e1-a879-0428313c6dbc,CMS2

TCGA-F4-6459-01Z-00-DX1.80a78213-1137-4521-9d60-ac64813dec4c,CMS4

TCGA-A6-6653-01Z-00-DX1.e130666d-2681-4382-9e7a-4a4d27cb77a4,CMS1

File name example in its folder:

```
filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        #append the file name to the list
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root,file))
```

tiles\TCGA-3L-AA1B-01Z-00-DX1.8923A151-A690-40B7-9E5A-FCBEDFC2394F\TCGA-3L-AA1B-01Z-00-DX1.8923A151-A690-40B7-9E5A-FCBEDFC2394F [d=1.97863,x=30166,y=17368,w=1013,h=1013].jpg’

Here is the screenshot of the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoH6e.png)

Answer (score 0):

os.walk should solve the problem for you.
In python you have to use "/" as separator between folders or files not the backslash .
You can use os.path.join() to join two files or folders or folder and file, or you can use pathlib library for this.

If you provide the root path to os.walk() library, underneath subfolders or files will automatically gets added.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it doesn't work for me. I want to load all image files in all subfolders and assign each folder's label for its files in it .  I add a screenshot of the result in the main question. please check it